# How can I specify a different number of users for each thread group individually on Blazemeter/JMeter?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, configuration, blazemeter

I have a few thread groups in JMeter. I want to run the test in Blazemeter. How can I have a different number of users for each thread group when running in Blazemeter?

It seems there is no option to change the number of users for every thread group. I can only specify the number of users which will be used for every thread group. I.e. if I have 2 thread groups and I specify 47 users on Blazemeter, then I will get 47 users for one thread group and 47 users for another.

Is there an option to specify the configuration specifically for every thread group?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen `Disabling these settings will use the values configured in the test script.` stanza?

[image]

Just toggle these blue sliders to turn BlazeMeter override off and settings from the .jmx script will be used.

If you want to control the number of threads from BlazeMeter web interface you can define the number of threads in Thread Groups via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and use [JMeter Properties](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261982219921-JMeter-Properties-JMeter-Properties) for providing the values.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the total number of Users gets divided into the ratio of the number of Users each thread group has.
Like if there are 100 Users and if you have 3 thread groups with

- Thread Group1: 5 Users
- Thread Group2: 3 Users
- Thread Group3: 2 Users

then, for the test, following will be the number of Users to each of the thread groups:

- Thread Group1: 50 Users
- Thread Group2: 30 Users
- Thread Group3: 20 Users

Ref: https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261977385233-Load-Configuration#h_01FCYANX1PW58PZR08S7FGYNA6